# LINQ to SQL Many to Many Comparison Query

Tags: algorithm, linq-to-sql, asp.net-membership

I have just finished creating a custom role provider using LINQ to SQL for data access. One of the functions you need to write for the provider is to remove users from roles;

```
public void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] rolenames);
```

Now one approach would be;

1. return a list of roles
2. iterate for each role and remove that role from all users that have that role

This approach is far from efficient I would like to know if there are better ways to handle this type of problem in LINQ to SQL.

Is there a way to create a select statement in LINQ to SQL that will take a string array for comparison, instead of looping and making N number of selects? Any approach better than what I described above would be much appreciated.

Tables Involved:

```
User (RecordID, Username)
Role (RecordID, Rolename)
UsersInRole (RoleID,UserID)
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
var uirQuery = from uir in db.UsersInRole
               join u in db.User on uir.UserID equals u.RecordID
               join r in db.Role on uir.RoleID equals r.RecordID
               where usernames.Contains(u.Username) 
                  && rolenames.Contains(r.Rolename)
               select uir;

db.UsersInRole.DeleteAllOnSubmit(uirQuery);
```

LINQ to SQL translates the "Contains" expression to a T-SQL IN clause.

Comment: Just to improve your code:
I'd easily write the full words in that query to make it *far* more readable: u => user, r => role, uir => usersInRole.

Comment: I would still have to loop this query for each user and role?

Comment: No .. that query would return all UsersInRole records that matched any combination of user + role as specified in the arguments to your method. You'd run the query just once to get (or delete, as in my example) the relevant records.